# Three card brag hand ranking? PHP

Tags: php

I'm finding it difficult to find a card ranking tutorial, or even some source code to read off to point me in the right direction.

I'm basically going in the direction of creating multiple functions with multiple `in_array` And writing them from scratch, as doing this will make it easy for three of a kind. Example

```
    function is_trip($card1, $card2, $card3) 
    {
        if (in_array($card1, $aces) && in_array($card2, $aces) && in_array($card3, $aces)) 
        {
            $score = 9500;
            $rank = 'Three Aces';
        }
        if (in_array($card1, $kings) && in_array($card2, $kings) && in_array($card3, $kings)) 
        {
            $score = 9000;
            $rank = 'Three Kings';
        }
    } And so on ...
```

So that would most likely work with trips, but then for a straight flush I would use a method of the way the cards are organized by number, as they're in the array in suit order.

So a straight flush would be hopefully as simple as `$highcard + $lowcard / 2 == $midcard` if that is true then you have a straight flush.

As for a straight, I'm stuck and would most likely have to use an array with my current mind set but writing that would seem like a lot of code when it is most likely simpler..

And for flushes it wouldn't be difficult to use the `in_array` as I'd only need to range `1-13` `14-26` `27-39` `40-52` in an `in_array` to determine a flush, but then I'd need `$highcard` value `$midcard` value to also play a role to determine a flush against others.

You may of got to this point and thought, `What's his question??`

Well, my question is.. Am I going the right way about ranking the cards, should I use a bucket counting method to put the ranks into a bit-code and use a lookup table? Or have you any advice on where I should be heading if my methods of doing it are completely stupid..

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is no valid code: `in_array($card1, 12, 25, 38, 51)`.

Comment: I was more writing pseudo code, I would write arrays for the `in_array` such as `in_array($card1, $aces)` My question is not based on being stuck in code, it's more stuck for anyone with experience to give me their knowledge on what I should be researching or path to be taking. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *very* rough, and untested, but what about something like: -

```
<?php
$hand = new Hand;
$hand->addCard(new Card(RankInterface::ACE, SuitInterface::SPADE));
$hand->addCard(new Card(RankInterface::QUEEN, SuitInterface::HEART));
$hand->addCard(new Card(RankInterface::KING, SuitInterface::CLUB));
$isFlush = isFlush($hand);
```

Using something like: -

```
<?php
namespace Card;

interface SuitInterface {
    const
        SPADE   = 'spade',
        HEART   = 'heart',
        DIAMOND = 'diamond',
        CLUB    = 'club';
}

interface RankInterface {
    const
        JOKER   = 0,
        ACE     = 1,
        TWO     = 2,
        THREE   = 3,
        FOUR    = 4,
        FIVE    = 5,
        SIX     = 6,
        SEVEN   = 7,
        EIGHT   = 8,
        NINE    = 9,
        TEN     = 10,
        JACK    = 11,
        QUEEN   = 12,
        KING    = 13;
}

class Card {
    protected
        $rank,
        $suit;

    public function __construct($rank, $suit) {
        $this->rank = $rank;
        $this->suit = $suit;
    }

    public function getRank() {
        return $this->rank;
    }

    public function getSuit() {
        return $this->suit;
    }

    public function isSameRank(Card $card) {
        return $this->getRank() === $card->getRank();
    }

    public function isSameSuit(Card $card) {
        return $this->getSuit() === $card->getSuit();
    }
}

class Hand
{
    protected
        $storage = array();

    public function addCard(Card $card) {
        $this->storage[] = $card;
        return $this;
    }

    public function asArray() {
        return $this->storage;
    }
}

function isFlush(Hand $hand) {

    $cards = $hand->asArray();

    $first = array_shift($cards);

    foreach($cards as $card) {
        if( ! $first->isSameSuit($card)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You would then just need to add some individual pieces of logic for the various valid hands/combos.

Comment: Thanks for your input, on waiting for the respond I've made a much messier one. I will now pursue this method. "I did manage to get all hands ranking though."